# Font used in Triforce and Overwatch logos

Tags: font-identification

Recently, while reading up on old/obsolete console systems, I noticed that the font used in Nintendo/Namco/Sega's Triforce system's logo (see also https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Triforce) was pretty much the same that Blizzard used in their Overwatch text logo.

Compare:
[image: Overwatch logo]
[image: Triforce logo]

Obviously, there are slight differences here and there, but the base font is pretty much the same.

Does anyone know by chance what the base font is?
I've checked WhatTheFont and Fontsquirrel, but neither site's font finder has been of any help.

Comment: I just tried using FontSquirrel, and it [shows several similar fonts](https://imgur.com/a/qtSj4) that could be modified.

Comment: I got pretty much the same result when using FontSquirrel. But as you said, they're merely similar, and thus, not what I want.

Comment: The examples you posted look like the letter forms have been modified, as in a custom design. If so, an exact match may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's safe to assume that since it's used in a well known logo - or a logo at all for that matter - that this is not going to be an "out-of-the-box" typeface. Looks like this is a modified version of [Bank Sans Caps Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ef/bank-sans-caps-ef/bold/):

[image]

Comment: I agree that it looks like Black Sans Caps Bold but that font came out in May 5, 2010. The triforce was in development around 2001

Comment: Yes, good point. This font is actually a part of a revival release of Bank Gothic, which was designed by Morris Fuller Benton back in the 1930s (digitized in the 1980s by the Mergenthaler Linotype Company). While very close in look, I felt that the weight of Bank Sans Bold was a little bit closer of a match.

Comment: Interesting history! There's a chance then that logo designers drew inspiration from that. I definitely think it looks close.

Answer (score 0):

The Trifoce logo was definitely made in house by either Sega, Namco, or Nintendo. Possibly created by all 3 at the same time around 2001 during it's development.

**You won't be able to find a font for it.**

The best you can do is find a similar style font. You will never be able to find the exact font.

As far as Overwatch goes, that's also a custom logo too, not a font.

The creators of these logos may have started off with a generic font and tweaked it to achieve a custom look. You  will have to do the same if that's the case.

**Unless you can talk to the art team you wont know.**

Comment: In fact for tweakability reasons even if i had a font like this i would just redraw it as it allows me to manipulate the things by stroke centers.